# Google drive api requests for specific users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk

We would like to generate a domain level report about the mail/drive usage for individual users so we can see where they are w/r to their allocated space.  Can i specify a user for my request, which ultimately allows me to iterate through a user list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use domain-wide delegation to impersonalize any user in the domain. Details are explained on https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation